# puppet giving class is not found

Tags: puppet

I was trying to write a module for epel repo.

here is the content of that module.

```
[root@ manifests]# cat init.pp
class epel {
            file { "/etc/yum.repos.d/epel.repo":
            ensure  => "present",
            mode    => "400",
            owner   => "root",
            group   => "root",
            source => "puppet://$puppetmaster/modules/yumrepos/files/epel.repo"
}
```

}

While applying this module to client side, I am getting following error.

Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 400 on SERVER: Could not find class epel for

Please tell me where will be the error exists.

Thanks in adv
Sankar

Answer (score 1):

The `class epel` will only be located if the `init.pp` file is in the `epel` module.

Make sure that

- The file is in the `manifests` subdirectory
- The `epel` tree (including `manifests/`) is in a module search directory of the current environment
- There is no other epel module (this is pretty far fetched, though)

Note that you probably want to use [the yumrepo type](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/latest/type.html#yumrepo) to manage repositories, instead of deploying prepared configuration files.